# How is this passage probably meant?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X=\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$. Let $\mathfrak{B}$ denote the Borel field on $X$ generated by its topology and let $\mu_{p_0,p_1,p_2}$ be product measure on $X$ in which the $i$'s have density $p_i$

1.) What exactly is $\mathfrak{B}$, i.e. what means "generated by its topology"? How can I imagine $\mathfrak{B}$?

2.) Same confusion with for $\mu_{p_0,p_1,p_2}$. How exactly does this measure look like, what does it do?

---

1.) As far as I see for $d=1$ it is meant that $\left\{0,1,2\right\}$ has the discrete topology and so $\mathfrak{B}(\left\{0,1,2\right\})$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all subsets of $\left\{0,1,2\right\}$. Further
$$
\mathfrak{B}(X)=\mathfrak{B}(\left\{0,1,2\right\})^{\bigotimes\mathbb{Z}}=\sigma\left(\left\{\prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}A_i: (A_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\in\prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathfrak{B}(\left\{0,1,2\right\})\right\}\right)
$$

In words: $\mathfrak{B}(X)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains the bi-infite cartesian products of subsets of $\left\{0,1,2\right\}$.

2.) As far as I do understand I think it is meant that for example for the set $\mathfrak{B}(X)\ni A=\left\{0\right\}\times\left\{1\right\}\times\left\{0\right\}\times\left\{1\right\}\times\cdots$ it is
$$
\mu_{p_0,p_1,p_2}(A)=p_0\cdot p_1\cdot p_0\cdot p_1\cdots.
$$

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I make an edit.